# Python logging does not write errors happened in try part of an exception handling

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

I tried using built-in logging in Python but the problem is it does not write errors happened for my exception handling parts. I mean if the error happens outside the try part it logs the error (warning level) but when the error is inside try there are no logs!
Can you please help me how can I make this work? Possibly without adding lines to all exception part?

The code that writes logs to file as I am expecting:

```py
from flask import Flask
from logging import FileHandler, WARNING

app = Flask(name)

# Writes occured exceptions to a file
file_handler = FileHandler('errorlogs.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(WARNING)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 1/0

if name == "main":
    app.run(port=6124)
```

How my real code is written and I want to log if any exception happens in any endpoint but I am not successful.

```py
from flask import Flask
from logging import FileHandler, WARNING

app = Flask(__name__)

# Writes occured exceptions to a file
file_handler = FileHandler('errorlogs.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(WARNING)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    try:
        return 1/0
    except:
        print("An exception occured")
        return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=6124)
```

Comment: you are using `print` in the except block, this will not use the logger. replace the `print` line with `app.logger.error("An exception occured")`

Comment: @ilias-sp This is also not printing

Comment: @ilias-sp the thing you said works but isn't there a more convenient way to do this? I mean should I add this to all except part of my endpoints?

Comment: @john, this is how i am doing it too. You could check if you want to utilize the `app.errorhandler` , more info in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/errorhandling/)